# FluentValidation in a service layer?

Tags: validation, fluentvalidation, service-layer

I have been using FluentValidation on my View Models in ASP.NET MVC 3 and it works awesome!

I want to now use it as my validation engine for my domain objects inside my service layer.

Can you do complex validation schemes with it?

I am looking for something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly ISomeOtherService someOtherService;
    public MyService(ISomeOtherService someOtherService)
    {
        this.someOtherService = someOtherService;
    }

    public bool SaveObject()
    {
        var validator = new MyValidator(someOtherService);
        if (!validator.IsValid())
        {
            //spin through the validation results, add them to IValidationDictionary which is a ModelState wrapper

            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject>
{
    private readonly IOtherService service;
    public MyValidator(ISomeOtherService service)
    {
        // Here I want to be able to perform complex validation rules that may involve other services??
    }
}
```

Something like this. Also I am open to using another validation lib/scheme?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a `ValidationService` combined with a `ValidatorFactory`, it is a pretty slick solution I think.

Here is the thread on the `ValidatorFactory`: [FluentValidation Autofac ValidatorFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225140/fluentvalidation-autofac-validatorfactory)