# FluentValidation Autofac ValidatorFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, fluentvalidation

I need to be able to provide the `IComponentContext` to my `ValidatorFactory` to resolve FluentValidation Validators. I am a little stuck.

ValidatorFactory

```
    public class ValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
    {
        private readonly IComponentContext context;

        public ValidatorFactory(IComponentContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
        {
            return context.Resolve(validatorType) as IValidator;
        }
    }
```

How do I provide the context and register the `ValidatorFactory`

```
FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. If you have the `ValidatorFactory` take `IComponentContext`, Autofac injects it automatically.

ValidatorFactory

```
    public class ValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
    {
        private readonly IComponentContext context;

        public ValidatorFactory(IComponentContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
        {
            return context.Resolve(validatorType) as IValidator;
        }
    }
```

Register the `ValidatorFactory`

```
FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = new ValidatorFactory());
```

Comment: You should supply the correct code in your answer, and then also mark it as the answer.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The code is correct. I have accepted my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than tightly couple it to Autofac, you can make it generally applicable to any `DependencyResolver` by using that directly:

```
public class ModelValidatorFactory : IValidatorFactory
{
  public IValidator GetValidator(Type type)
  {
    if (type == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    }
    return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(type)) as IValidator;
  }

  public IValidator<T> GetValidator<T>()
  {
    return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IValidator<T>>();
  }
}
```

Then you can register your validators with any type of `DependencyResolver` as the strongly-typed `IValidator<T>` and it will always end up resolving.

Comment: Nice! I like it... I marked yours as the answer instead of mine just for the fact that it is generic now! Thanks